# How do I match clusters within an image to find copy-move forgery

Tags: image, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I am trying to implement this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8269716/) on copy-move forgery in matlab. I have created clusters  using selected keypoints. And now I need to identify the matching clusters and mark them with each other . But I could not find any understandable method to match the clusters. It would be helpful if someone could advice me on this.
As an example, I extracted and marked clusters in this image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should *first* match the keypoints.

Clustering the matched key points is easier, you can likely represent them as x,y vectors. Maybe for rescaling and rotations, a Hough transform may be useful for more robust processing. But that all relies on first finding the best matches. Clustering then is a simple mode seeking.

Comment: My concern is, matching the keypoints alone, won't cover a region(or a specific area). So what I have done is(according to the paper), 1)Extracted the keypoints from the image(using SIFT) 2)Separated the matching keypoints(in order to avoid, creation of unnecessary clusters, thus to reduce computation) 3)Extracted clusters from the matching keypoints(please refer the image in question) Finally, I need to connect those matching clusters. In this case(as I understand it. Pardon, if I'm wrong), clusters are generated to highlight the 'regions' that are forged.

Comment: There is nothing forged in above image. As far I can tell, this is an artistic editing involving a copy, but no forgery.

Comment: Use a more difficult image! Once you get bad matches, clustering the matching vectors will work much better. As single matches can be bad, you want a cluster of *consistent* matches.